# Why does type inference in mutable and immutable sets behave so differently?

Tags: scala, type-inference

I got some strange results when running the following code:

```
object Example {

  implicit object StringOrdering extends Ordering[String] {
    def compare(o1: String, o2: String) = {
      o1.length - o2.length
    }
  }
  object StringOrdering1 extends Ordering[String] {
    def compare(o1: String, o2: String) = {
      o2.length - o1.length
    }
  }


  import collection.mutable
  import collection.immutable.TreeSet

  val x = TreeSet(1, 5, 8, 12)
  val y = mutable.Set.empty ++= x // mutable.Set[Int]
  val y1 = mutable.Set.empty[Int] ++= x // mutable.Set[Int]
  val z = TreeSet.empty ++ y // Set[Any]
  val z1 = TreeSet.empty[Int] ++ y // TreeSet[Int]
}
```

Why does type inference in mutable and immutable sets behave so differently? The `z` part is most puzzling, why didn't we at least get a `TreeSet[Any]`?

Comment: The `z` line doesn't compile on either 2.10 or 2.11.

Comment: There must be some implicit `Ordering` in scope not shown here that is not `Ordering[Int]` for this even to compile.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem can be simplified to something like this:

```
scala> TreeSet.empty[Int] ++ TreeSet.empty[BigInt]
res15: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Any] = Set()
```

Your use of `TreeSet.empty` doesn't reveal what type it actually is. In fact, it doesn't even compile as-is. I'm operating under the assumption that you have some implicit `Ordering[A]` in scope you're not showing, where `A != Int`.

On to the question:

> Why didn't we at least get a TreeSet[Any]

The simple answer is that you cannot have a `TreeSet[Any]` without an `Ordering[Any]`. If I try to combine  a `TreeSet[Int]` with a `TreeSet[BigInt]`, their most common type is `Any`. A `TreeSet` is a type of `SortedSet`, but how can we sort a set of `Any`? By default, we can't, because it doesn't really make sense to sort a set of `Any`.

I could contrive an `Ordering[Any]` if I really wanted to, and I would end up with a `TreeSet[Any]`:

```
implicit val ordAny = new Ordering[Any] {
    def compare(x: Any, y: Any): Int = Ordering.Int.compare(x.hashCode, y.hashCode)
}

scala> TreeSet.empty[Int] ++ TreeSet.empty[BigInt]
res8: scala.collection.immutable.TreeSet[Any] = TreeSet()
```

But this doesn't really make any sense.

The technical answer is that in order to concatenate two `TreeSet`s, `TreeSet[A]` and `TreeSet[B]`, we need an implicit `CanBuildFrom[TreeSet[A], B, TreeSet[B]]`.

There are *some* `CanBuildFrom`s generated by [`SortedSetFactory`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/0f72dd37f85bbcaa07cfb325685dc019e6bc1c26/src/library/scala/collection/generic/SortedSetFactory.scala#L31-L35), but notice how they require an implicit `Ordering[A]`. Because the `Ordering[Any]` cannot be found, the compiler looks for something more generic, and finds `Set[Any]`. This makes sense, because if we put elements into a sorted set that we don't know how to sort, then we no longer have a sorted set. What is left is just a plain `Set`.

Comment: Indeed, I have sent some code to the console and deleted it later (I am using intellij). The question is edited.